# Magento block in local.xml causing SQLSTATE syntax error

Tags: magento

I was getting a SQLSTATE [42000] access violation: 1064 error only when clicking on a product page.

I located the problem in local.xml and it had something to do with this specific block:

```
<!-- List Products by category in the main area-->
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" after="header.image" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>202</category_id></action>
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Can someone explain what I did wrong and why it's doing this? I'm trying to list a few products on the homepage while hiding the product list toolbar.

Thanks!

Comment: Which local.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

So, unfortunately local.xml is meant to have datebase configuration and stuff like that.

Configuration about the layout should be put in a layout.xml and you have to wrap it in a layout-tag like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured" after="header.image" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>202</category_id></action>
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</layout>
```

Comment: There's `app/etc/local.xml` which has database connections, but each Magento theme may also have a local.xml file where layout updates specific to the current installation are supposed to go.

Comment: Thanks Alan, you're right, I just assumed it's related to the database configuration as he mentioned to get a database error when calling that page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had the block wrapped in:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!--block here-->
    </default>
</layout>
```

When it needed to be in:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index>
        <!--block here-->
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

This ended up fixing the problem of getting a SQLSTATE syntax error when clicking into a product page.